# Multiple select dropdown not working with ng-option

Tags: html, angularjs, bootstrap-4

```
<select class="selectpicker" name="productName" ng-model="productName"
        style="width:250px" ng-options="x.name for x in preSalesSpocData"
        ng-change="getVersionsForProduct()">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Please Select Option</option>
</select>
```

Here I have a JSON object that is `preSalesSpocData` and I am trying to populate the dropdown using `ng-options`, but it is not working. When I am using normal select it is working fine , but `ng-options` not working with multiple select dropdown. Please, provide a solution for this.

Here is the sample of the JSON data:

```
$rootScope.preSalesSpocData = [
  { Id: 1, Name: 'Apple' }, 
  { Id: 2, Name: 'Mango' }, 
  { Id: 3, Name: 'Orange' }
];
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the JSON structure?

Comment: $rootScope.preSalesSpocData = [{
                Id: 1,
                Name: 'Apple'
            }, {
                Id: 2,
                Name: 'Mango'
            }, {
                Id: 3,
                Name: 'Orange'
            }];

                });

Comment: The above is sample json data.

Comment: you are selecting `x.name`, but your JSON has `Name` property

Comment: I have tried with x.Name as well. Not working.

Comment: For multi-select, add the `multiple` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Given your code and description for it, you have a working example. Here is a demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $rootScope.preSalesSpocData = [{
    Id: 1,
    Name: 'Apple'
  }, {
    Id: 2,
    Name: 'Mango'
  }, {
    Id: 3,
    Name: 'Orange'
  }];

  $scope.getVersionsForProduct = function() {
    console.log("getVersionsForProduct called");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <select multiple class="selectpicker" name="productName"
          ng-model="productName" style="width:250px"
          ng-options="x.Name for x in preSalesSpocData"
          ng-change="getVersionsForProduct()">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Please Select Option</option>
  </select>
  <pre>{{productName | json}}</pre>

</div>
```

You might have a typo, or you forgot to inject `$rootScope`, etc.

Comment: I want it to be a multi select drop down.

Comment: @nishantsingh simply add `multiple` attribute to your `<select>` tag

Answer (score 1):

try:`item as x.Name`

```
<select class="selectpicker" name="productName" ng-model="productName"  style="width:250px"ng-options="item as x.Name for item in preSalesSpocData" ng-change="getVersionsForProduct()">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Please Select Option</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

please add like below with multiple ng-model and check

Example

```
<select  ng-model="empInfo1" >
<select  ng-model="empInfo2" >
```

Comment: This is also not working, since we have ng-model already there in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your ng-options should follow syntax `element.property for element in listOfElements`.

Therefore you should have `ng-options="item.Name for item in preSalesSpocData"`

**EDIT**: In reply to the comment, this is working just fine.
See [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Protozoid/0e8t41wg/).

Comment: Its same way only, x.Name for x in preSalesSpocData